# Native gui toolkit for Ubuntu, past, present, and future

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gtk, x11

I can't find a definitive answer to this question: What is the actual, real, native, no-wrapper gui toolkit of Ubuntu?

I may fundamentally misunderstand something about the way that it works in linux, but I know that in Windows, for example, there are the low-level C APIs that comprise Windows's native windowing tooklit, and then various wrappers (such as that C++ library I can't remember the name of at the moment). But the actual native API is the C one.

On linux, there is no native gui; it's just a kernel. But in Ubuntu there's X11, GTK, Qt, and others, and I don't know what the REAL native toolkit is. I know that at least for Ubuntu Touch Canonical is moving to Qt as the native toolkit, but even in that case, will Qt be the REAL native toolkit, or is it just going to be a wrapper around X11, Mir, or something else?

Comment: You're looking for something that doesn't exist, but Qt is a fine substitute.

Comment: I've always thought of the native toolkit as the one which creates the dialogs, on any particular buffer.  X does have it's own native widgets, but the community moved away from them for the modern libs.  So really there are many native kits, Gtk, QT, Fltk.. etc.  In general I'd follow this general rule, C++ ok? Use Qt.  C only? Gtk. Also avoid calling xlib.h, to prepare for easier Wayland usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux distros don't have a "native toolkit". Qt and GTK call the XLib, but the switch to Wayland is in progress, and Mir looks like a terrible idea for me. Anyway, the real low-level thing is: XLib, Wayland, or Mir. And the GUI toolkits, GTK, Qt are above these, and transparently use the right backend. Other toolkits like wxWidgets are on top of the "native toolkit" of the platform. For Linux, they chose GTK.

Ubuntu is moving to Qt, but was previously GTK, so you can't predict what it will be in the future. But the integration of your app depends on what your user runs as a desktop environment, so Qt or GTK are the best options. Qt is better for Windows portability, though.

Comment: I thought that might be the way it worked. Thanks for the info.